# Как вывести значения ACF wordpress в модальном окне?

Tags: php, wordpress

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при просмотре записи в модальном окне с аяксом показывается контент из группы полей (ACF) только для первой записи и не показывается слайдер (flexslider), точнее он показывается но только точки и стрелки навигации.

functions.php

```
function artisansweb_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapcss', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), false, 'all');
      
    wp_register_script('bootstrapjs', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapjs');
  
    wp_register_script('custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
    // Localize the script with new data
    $script_data_array = array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'security' => wp_create_nonce( 'view_post' ),
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'custom-script', 'blog', $script_data_array );
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-script');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'artisansweb_scripts');

function load_post_by_ajax_callback() {
    check_ajax_referer('view_post', 'security');
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'p' => $_POST['id'],
    );
     
    $posts = new WP_Query( $args );
     
    $arr_response = array();
    if ($posts->have_posts()) {
         
        while($posts->have_posts()) {
             
            $posts->the_post();
             
            $arr_response = array(
                'title' => get_the_title(),
                'content' => get_the_content(),
            );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
     
    echo json_encode($arr_response);
     
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_load_post_by_ajax', 'load_post_by_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_post_by_ajax', 'load_post_by_ajax_callback');
```

Вывод цикла с модальным окном

```
// Start posts query
    if( $query->have_posts() ): ?>

        <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( "am_post_grid am__col-3 am_layout_{$args['layout']} {$args['animation']} " ); ?>">

        <?php while( $query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal" id="postModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog" style="max-width:70%">
                    <div class="modal-content" >
                        <div class="modal-body">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="float:right"></button>

                                                    <div class="row-popup">
                                                        <div class="col-popup" style="min-width: 545px;">

                                                            <?php if( have_rows('portfolio-gallery') ): ?>
                                                                    <div class="flexslider">
                                                                        <ul class="slides">
                                                                    <?php while( have_rows('portfolio-gallery') ) : the_row();

                                                                    $image = get_sub_field('image');
                                                                    $imageurl = $image['sizes']['slider'];
                                                                    ?>

                                                                    <li><img src="<?php echo $imageurl; ?>"></li>

                                                                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                                                                </ul>
                                                                </div>
                                                            <?php endif; ?>

                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-popup" style="width:40%">
                                                            <div class="portfolio-title">Игра <?php $value = get_field("portfolio-game-type"); echo $value;?></div>
                                                            <div class="portfolio-customer">заказчик: <?php the_field('portfolio-customer'); ?></div>
                                                                <div class="portfolio-review"><?php the_field('portfolio-review'); ?></div>
                                                                <div class="portfolio-price"><?php the_field('quantity-and-price'); ?></div>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </div>

                                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php if($args['layout'] == "1"){ ?>
            <div class="am_grid_col" >
                <div class="am_single_grid view-post">
                    <div class="am_thumb">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="am_cont">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><h2 class="am__title"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2></a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } else if( $args['layout'] == 2 ){ ?>
            <?php } ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
```

Скрипт

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('body').on('click', '.view-post', function() {
        var data = {
            'action': 'load_post_by_ajax',
            'id': $(this).data('id'),
            'security': blog.security
        };
  
        $.post(blog.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            response = JSON.parse(response);
            $('#postModal h5#postModalLabel').text(response.title);
            $('#postModal .modal-body').html(response.content);
  
            var postModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('postModal'));
            postModal.show();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Возможно оно не понимает к от каких именно постов вы хотите получить поля ACF. Что выдает `var_dump()` того запроса что вы дергаете?

Comment: да не понимал. все верно, но сообразил где неправильно делал.

Comment: Но теперь другая проблема, не показывает галерею ACF Prо, несколько дней бьюсь не могу понять почему %)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в скрипте добавить строчки с новым id:
`$('#postModal .modal-body #postModalField').html(response.field_name);` 
 
в functions.php добавить: 
`'field_name' => get_field('acf-field'),`
в коде модального окна для вывода поля в нужном месте установить id из скрипта:
 `<div class="modal-body"><p class="custom" id="postModalField"></p></div>`

Comment: Помогло? Теперь отображает ?

Comment: Да, показывает все нужные поля, но галерею acf pro так и не получается вывести.